# Can I upgrade an Access MDE database to Access 2007 ACCDE format using VBA only?

Tags: ms-access-2007, upgrade, ms-access-2003

I would like to provide the facility for the user to upgrade their own back-end databases rather than sending the file to me to manually convert using Access.

Is this possible? Having read around the subject I don't have much hope but would like expert confirmation it is impossible or hopefully a solution.

Comment: [Application.ConvertAccessProject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193465(v=office.15).aspx) might do it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, that looked promising but it only works with non-encoded databases i.e. MDB and ACCDB, not MDE or ACCDE. Thanks.

Comment: Try this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3abbfc1b-a945-4667-b01a-41040c01aab8/programmatical-convertion-of-mdb-to-accdb?forum=accessdev

Comment: I saw it before but it does seem to only encode MDB databases to MDE.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why the back-end database files are .mde/.accde files?

Comment: @GordThompson Yes, they hold confidential and encrypted data.

Comment: As I tried to explain in my answer to your earlier Super User question [here](http://superuser.com/q/714174/207964), a *compiled* database (saved as .accde) and an *encrypted* database (with a database password assigned) are **two completely separate issues**. You can have an encrypted database file that is saved as an .accdb file.

Comment: But FYI, the author of file (not me) initially only compiled it to protect the code and thinking it would also protect the data but he didn't encrypt it. I inherited only the MDE/ACCDE files to work with and encrypted them also to properly protect the data. The original MDB/ACCDB files are missing. So what I meant was: there is confidential code and confidential data so it is both encoded and encrypted. And, of course, it is much easier to distribute smaller MDE/ACCDE files than the full MDB/ACCDB files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are really limited to just MDE/ACCDE format, this appears to be impossible.

One imperfect way you could do it, if you only use tables and queries, is to create a new database in the desired format, and import the tables and queries from the old database. This is because using the MDE/ACCDE format, you cannot import or export forms, modules, and macros. To try this produces the error:

> Error 29045: Description: "You can't import, export, create, modify, or rename any forms, reports, pages or modules in an ACCDE, MDE or ADE database."

If using just tables and queries you could go ahead as follows based on the example given in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/298174

(In my scenario, I am not able to use the new database as the current database so I must import into the current database temporarily and then export into the new database, otherwise just directly import into the new database.)

```
Dim strNewDB As String
Dim strOldDB As String
Dim dbOld as Database
Dim dbNew as Database
Dim tbl As Variant
Dim qry As QueryDef

Set dbNew = DBEngine.CreateDatabase(strNewDB, dbLangGeneral & ";pwd=xxxxx"), dbEncrypt)
Set dbOld = DBEngine.OpenDatabase(strOldDB, , , ";pwd=xxxxx")) 

'import/export tables
For Each tbl In dbOld.TableDefs
    Debug.Print tbl.name
    If left(tbl.name, 4) <> "MSys" Then            
        DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", dbOld.name, acTable, _
            tbl.name, "_temp_" & tbl.name                
        DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Access", dbNew.name, acTable, _
         "_temp_" & tbl.name, tbl.name             
        DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "_temp_" & tbl.name            
    End If
Next tbl

'import/export queries
For Each qry In dbOld.QueryDefs
    Debug.Print qry.name
    DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", dbOld.name, acQuery, _
            qry.name, "_temp_" & qry.name                
    DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Access", dbNew.name, acQuery, _
           "_temp_" & qry.name, qry.name               
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "_temp_" & qry.name
Next qry
```

As mentioned by [Robert Harvey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102937/robert-harvey) in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23350869/can-i-upgrade-an-access-mde-database-to-access-2007-accde-format-using-vba-only/23373988#comment35761834_23350869), when using MDB/ACCDB you could just use Application.ConvertAccessProject.